# Payment method custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, payment-methods, duplicate

How to duplicate config.xml file for payment methods custom module in magento1.9.

Comment: Can you write more about it?

Comment: i want to use the same blocks, helpers, models,sql and contollers...etc from the existed payment custom module

Comment: Move all file into your module and change the class name.

Comment: Only be aware of method code name, that is unique.

Comment: No, i wants to add within that module duplicate the content and use the same code.thanks

Comment: while changing config.xml file, changes are not applying